# Changing the letters in a string to upper case and lower case before an inputted letter

Tags: python, string, list

I have a question that I have almost figured out but am stuck on one aspect of it.  The question asks me to create a function that takes a letter as a parameter that scans a list of capitals and returns a list of  those capitals containing that letter.  But it also turns the capital all lower case and makes the letter before and after the parameter letter uppercase.  I have been able to figure out how to do it when there is only a single letter but in the case of the capital brazzaville where the parameter letter is 'z' I am struggling to get it to  return it as brAzzAville.   Ican only get it to return brAzZaville.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
    def get_funny_case_capital_cities(letter):
        my_list = []
        for element in capitals:
            if letter.lower() in element.lower():
               capital_city = list(element.lower())
               capital_city.append("")
               for i, name in enumerate(capital_city):
                       if name == letter:
                               capital_city[i] = capital_city[i].lower()
                               capital_city[i-1] = (capital_city[i-1].upper())
                               capital_city[i+1] = (capital_city[i+1].upper())
                capital_city.pop()
                capital_city = "".join(capital_city)
    my_list.append(capital_city)
return my_list


    print(get_funny_case_capital_cities('z'))
```

this gives me an output of:
['brAzZaville', 'zAgreb', 'vadUz']

capitals is a list of all country capitals in the world.

```
     capitals = (
'Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires', 'Yerevan',
'Canberra', 'Vienna', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Manama', 'Dhaka', 'Bridgetown', 'Minsk', 'Brussels', 'Belmopan',
'Porto Novo',
'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Sarajevo', 'Gaborone', 'Brasilia', 'Bandar Seri Begawan', 'Sofia', 'Ouagadougou', 'Gitega',
'Phnom Penh', 'Yaounde', 'Ottawa', 'Praia', 'Bangui', "N'Djamena", 'Santiago', 'Beijing', 'Bogota', 'Moroni',
'Kinshasa', 'Brazzaville', 'San Jose', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Zagreb', 'Havana', 'Nicosia', 'Prague', 'Copenhagen',
'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Santo Domingo', 'Dili', 'Quito', 'Cairo', 'San Salvador', 'London', 'Malabo', 'Asmara',
'Tallinn', 'Mbabana', 'Addis Ababa', 'Palikir', 'Suva', 'Helsinki', 'Paris', 'Libreville', 'Banjul', 'Tbilisi',
'Berlin', 'Accra', 'Athens', "Saint George's", 'Guatemala City', 'Conakry', 'Bissau', 'Georgetown',
'Port au Prince',
'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Reykjavik', 'New Delhi', 'Jakarta', 'Tehran', 'Baghdad', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Rome',
'Kingston', 'Tokyo', 'Amman', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Nairobi', 'Tarawa Atoll', 'Pristina', 'Kuwait City', 'Bishkek',
'Vientiane', 'Riga', 'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Monrovia', 'Tripoli', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Antananarivo',
'Lilongwe', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Male', 'Bamako', 'Valletta', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis', 'Mexico City',
'Chisinau', 'Monaco', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Podgorica', 'Rabat', 'Maputo', 'Nay Pyi Taw', 'Windhoek',
'No official capital',
'Kathmandu', 'Amsterdam', 'Wellington', 'Managua', 'Niamey', 'Abuja', 'Pyongyang', 'Skopje', 'Belfast', 'Oslo',
'Muscat', 'Islamabad', 'Melekeok', 'Panama City', 'Port Moresby', 'Asuncion', 'Lima', 'Manila', 'Warsaw', 'Lisbon',
'Doha', 'Bucharest', 'Moscow', 'Kigali', 'Basseterre', 'Castries', 'Kingstown', 'Apia', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome',
'Riyadh', 'Edinburgh', 'Dakar', 'Belgrade', 'Victoria', 'Freetown', 'Singapore', 'Bratislava', 'Ljubljana',
'Honiara',
'Mogadishu', 'Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Madrid', 'Colombo', 'Khartoum', 'Paramaribo',
'Stockholm', 'Bern', 'Damascus', 'Taipei', 'Dushanbe', 'Dodoma', 'Bangkok', 'Lome', "Nuku'alofa", 'Port of Spain',
'Tunis', 'Ankara', 'Ashgabat', 'Funafuti', 'Kampala', 'Kiev', 'Abu Dhabi', 'London', 'Washington D.C.',
'Montevideo',
'Tashkent', 'Port Vila', 'Vatican City', 'Caracas', 'Hanoi', 'Cardiff', "Sana'a", 'Lusaka', 'Harare')
```

I am stuck on getting it too skip the second repeated letter.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code is incomplete.

Comment: sorry, my apologies.  i have added the list of capitals

Comment: And what happens when you copy and paste that entire block of code into your IDE and run it?  Are you trying to tell us that you get the output you claim?  Again, refer to the link I provided.

Comment: sorry, i am still learning - i think i have done it correctly now,  thanks for the help!

Comment: Your code is not minimal, and dies on syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to walk through this logic, perhaps using pencil & paper:

```
            capital_city[i] = capital_city[i].lower()
            capital_city[i-1] = (capital_city[i-1].upper())
            capital_city[i+1] = (capital_city[i+1].upper())
```

Note the trailing `upper` call in this trio: you capitalize position `i-1`, even if you've already determined that it must be lower case in the previous iteration.

Instead, just check to see whether it's the target letter:

```
            capital_city[i] = capital_city[i].lower()
            if i > 0 and capital_city[i-1] != letter:
                capital_city[i-1] = (capital_city[i-1].upper())
            if if i < len(capital_city)-1 and capital_city[i+1] != letter:
                capital_city[i+1] = (capital_city[i+1].upper())
```

Comment: I think it should be `if i > 0 and capital_city[i - 1] != letter:` and 
`if i < len(capital_city) - 1 and capital_city[i + 1] != letter:` so index out of bound errors don't occur if the target letter is the first or last letter.